# Set value for every select element - Java Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select second option for every drop down(select element) available on page.

I am aware that i could use syntax:

```
dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("accountConsultant")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

But i have dozens of select elements on one page and few pages. I would like to iterate entire page and set index(1) for every drop down without syntax above for every single drop down, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findElements()` by the "tag name", loop over each element found, instantiate `Select` object and select the value by index:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("select")); 

for (WebElement element: elements) {
      dropdown = new Select(element);
      dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
}
```